# JSON Parsing (700 KB file) taking over 30 seconds with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jackson

I have an android app that has to parse a JSON file. Initially, I was using the built in JSON.org parser, but it was taking about 30 seconds to run the `JSONArray node1=new JSONArray(response);` command alone.

I saw someone recommending Jackson, so I gave that a whirl and it might have made the issue even worse.

My call `JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(responseString);` is taking about 20 seconds.

Also, the following lines take about another 10 seconds:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<List<Dealership>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Dealership>>(){};
List<Dealership> dealerships = mapper.readValue(rootNode.traverse(), typeRef);
```

Should it really be taking this long to parse? Once I have my array, my code runs quickly, it is getting to that point which is taking so much time.

Is there something I can be doing to optimize my code? Should I try something other than Jackson or should I be using Jackson in some other way?

Comment: You are parsing twice. Just use `mapper.readValue(responseString, typeRef)` directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Haha well that is a bit embarrassing. Thanks for the help! Much better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will notice that `ObjectMapper#readTree(..)` states

> Method to deserialize JSON content as tree expressed using set of
>   JsonNode instances.

So this parses the JSON once.

You will also notice that `ObjectMapper#readValue(..)` also states

> Method to deserialize JSON content into a non-container type (it can
>   be an array type, however): typically a bean, array or a wrapper type
>   (like java.lang.Boolean).

So you are actually parsing your JSON twice and that probably slows you down.

You can parse it once directly with

```
mapper.readValue(responseString, typeRef)
```